# How can I get the length of a generic data structure without knowing the type of data structure it will be?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, collections

I have created my own data structure that functions similarly to an ArrayDeque and extends an AbstractList. The point of it is to hold other data structures, but not allow structures that have more than a specified number of elements.

For example (my constructor):

```java
public MyD(Class<T> t, int limit) 
{
}
```

Where limit determines the amount of elements allowed per data structure added to the ArrayDeque.

My issue is that, because I'm using generics, I don't technically know what type of data structure I'm working with at the time.

```
public void add(int i, T structure) {}
```

Where structure could be anything from an array, to ArrayList, to Queue, etc.

My question: Is there a way to take a generic value and generically cast it to get the amount of elements within if I know it will always be some form of data structure.

I have tried casting it to a simply array[], but if a List is passed through, it will break the functionality.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
T[] array = (T[])x;

if(array.length > b) { return; }
```

Comment: If 2 arrays are added, one with 3 elements and next with 4 elements... do you consider the size of MyD to be 7 ?

Comment: @DariusX. No, the size of MyD would be 2. The size of the elements of MyD would be 3 and 4 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some reflection to test whether the passed structure is an array or a Collection and then get its size accordingly:

```
public void add(int i, T structure) {
    int size;
    if (structure.getClass().isArray()) {
        size = Array.getLength(structure);
    } else if (structure instanceof Collection) {
        size = ((Collection) structure).size();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Structure is neither an array nor a collection");
    }
    if (size > limit) {
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is a good starting point toward the answer and I implemented it, but for some reason it doesn't get whatever is being passed through the add function. 

I don't know what type of data structure is being passed unfortunately, but I set my size to -1 to catch if there's no change, and there's never any change.

Comment: @Kahl what do you mean by "it doesn't get whatever is being passed through the add function"? Can you share your full add method and how you call it?

Comment: @Holger you are right. Initially I was testing `Class<T> t` which is passed in the constructor, so I couldn't use `instanceof`. Bu then I replaced it with `structure.getClass()` to make it clearer.

Comment: This answered the main question for the most part so I'm marking it as the answer. Turns out I needed to also look at efficient linked lists as they use something called blocks.